# python contouring with different colors and different line styles

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour

I have two donut-shaped images. Both looks same but a bit different.
I want to show contouring outer circle and inner circle with different color and same thing for another picture but dotted curve. And then superimposed both pictures as one image.
I got this far..... Please help

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = cv2.imread('donut.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('E:/1/12.jpg',1)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in range(len(contours)):
    cv2.drawContours(image, contours,i, ((i+1)*128, 0, 0), 2)

plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```